# How to make updatable DataGridView of joined Entity Framework tables using Linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I want to use a DataGridView to display and update data from two joined MSSQL tables, but I can't work out how to show the data I want *and* make it updatable.

In this case, I want to display a bill of materials for a particular machine type ("HX" in the code below). 'Parts' are unique machine components (so contain the stock level, part drawing etc.) whereas 'Items' are 'instances' of a part in a particular context or assembly within a machine, so contain quantity, description etc. for that use.

From the DB/model point of view these tables have a many (Items) to one (Part) relationship.

The code below shows all the Linq query structures I can think of, none of which does everything I need:

```
Public Class Form1

    ' Entity Framework members
    Private context As New EJEFData.CorporateEntities

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ' This displays ALL 'Item' fields and can be updated via the DataGridView. 
        ' However, it doesn't show any of the related 'Part' fields which I need
        Dim data1 = From i In context.Items
                    Where i.Type = "HX"
                    Order By i.Item1
                    Select i

        ' This displays all the columns I want (and no more) and demonstrates the the magic of entity framework as the table join
        ' is all part of the model! However, the output is read only so can't change the data.
        Dim data2 = From i In context.Items
                    Where i.Type = "HX"
                    Order By i.Item1
                    Select i.Part.Stock, i.Model, i.Item1, i.Part.DrawingType, i.Description, i.Part.Supplier, i.Part.SuppliersDescription, i.Qty, i.Status

        ' This displays just two columns on the DataGridView: text representations of the the particular 'Part' and 'Item' classes...
        Dim data3 = From i In context.Items
                    Join p In context.Parts On i.PartID Equals p.ID
                    Where i.Type = "HX"
                    Order By i.Item1
                    Select i, p
        ' ...However, the underlying data is there and can be edited by uncommenting:
        'Dim itemList = data3.ToList
        'itemList(0).i.Description = InputBox("New Value:",, itemList(0).i.Description)
        'm_context.SaveChanges()

        ' This seems to be another way of achieving data2 but with the join defined in the query rather than using the Entity Framework model structure
        ' Again, it is read only.
        Dim data4 = From i In context.Items
                    Join p In context.Parts On i.PartID Equals p.ID
                    Where i.Type = "HX"
                    Order By i.Item1
                    Select p.Stock, i.Model, i.Item1, p.DrawingType, i.Description, p.Supplier, p.SuppliersDescription, i.Qty, i.Status

        ' This dispays an editable DataGridView (perfect!) BUT doesn't save the changes back to the database
        Dim data5 = From i In context.Items
                    Where i.Type = "HX"
                    Order By i.Item1
                    Select New With {.Stock = i.Part.Stock, .Model = i.Model, .Item = i.Item1, .DrawingType = i.Part.DrawingType,
                            .Description = i.Description, .Supplier = i.Part.Supplier, .SuppliersDescription = i.Part.SuppliersDescription, .Qty = i.Qty, .Status = i.Status}

        ' Bind the data to the DataGridView via a BindingSource (data1 can be changed to data2, data3 etc.)
        PartBindingSource.DataSource = data1.ToList
        DataGridView1.DataSource = PartBindingSource
    End Sub

    ' Update the database when leaving a modified DataGridView row
    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowValidated
        context.SaveChanges()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have tried a low level approach using a dataset filled and updated with custom SQL queries but using that throughout my project would be prohibitively time consuming and error prone. In any case, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Entity Framework is Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for
>   new applications

However, if Entity Framework is really the wrong approach for this application then I'm happy to hear any other suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the 'Data1' approach from the question, but made an inherited DataGridView class that could accept nested properties in the column bindings (e.g. Part.Stock to get Item.Part.Stock). However, that means that these columns can't be autogenerated as there is no mechanism for automatically detecting which nested properties would be required.
See below for DataGridView code (I've taken out some questionable error checking so if it doesn't seem complete, that might be why). 
This basically works by reading the column binding path and if it contains '.' getting or setting the property using reflection.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic

Public Class NestedSourceGrid
    ' Inherits DataGridView in designer generated code

Private _commitAttempt As Boolean

''' <summary>
''' Stores list of properties for nested property bound columns
''' Key = column name
''' </summary>
Dim BindPropertyLists As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub

Private Function GetBindProperty(ByVal [property] As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
    Dim retValue As Object = Nothing

    If propertyName.Contains(".") Then
        Dim thisPropertyName As String

        thisPropertyName = propertyName.Substring(0, propertyName.IndexOf("."))
        propertyName = propertyName.Substring(propertyName.IndexOf(".") + 1)

        retValue = GetBindProperty([property].GetType().GetProperty(thisPropertyName).GetValue([property], Nothing), propertyName)
    Else
        ' Return this (bottom) property value
        Dim tempValue = [property].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue([property], Nothing)
        If tempValue Is Nothing Then Return ""
        retValue = tempValue
    End If

    Return retValue
End Function

Private Sub SetBindProperty(ByVal [property] As Object, ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal value As Object)

    ' If there are further property nest levels
    If propertyName.Contains(".") Then
        Dim thisPropertyName As String

        thisPropertyName = propertyName.Substring(0, propertyName.IndexOf("."))
        propertyName = propertyName.Substring(propertyName.IndexOf(".") + 1)

        SetBindProperty([property].GetType().GetProperty(thisPropertyName).GetValue([property], Nothing), propertyName, value)
    Else ' Bottom property level
        ' Set the value to this (bottom) property
        [property].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue([property], value)
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetBindPropertyType(ByVal propertyType As Type, ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal columnName As String) As Type
    Dim retValue As Type = Nothing

    ' If there are further property nest levels
    If propertyName.Contains(".") Then
        Dim thisPropertyName As String

        thisPropertyName = propertyName.Substring(0, propertyName.IndexOf("."))
        propertyName = propertyName.Substring(propertyName.IndexOf(".") + 1)

        retValue = GetBindPropertyType(propertyType.GetProperty(thisPropertyName).PropertyType, propertyName, columnName)
    Else ' Bottom property level
        Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo

        propertyInfo = propertyType.GetProperty(propertyName)
        retValue = propertyInfo.PropertyType
    End If

    Return retValue
End Function

Private Sub MultiSourceGrid_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles Me.RowsAdded
    If Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Clear the BindPropertyLists so Add can't throw exception
    BindPropertyLists.Clear()

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In Columns
        If col.DataPropertyName.Contains(".") Then
            ' Create new (empty) list for this column in BindPropertyLists
            BindPropertyLists.Add(col.Name, New List(Of String))
            col.ValueType = GetBindPropertyType(Rows(0).DataBoundItem.GetType, col.DataPropertyName, col.Name)

            ' Insert the values from 'complex bound' source objects
            For i As Integer = e.RowIndex To e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1
                Rows.Item(i).Cells.Item(col.Index).Value = GetBindProperty(Rows(i).DataBoundItem, col.DataPropertyName)
            Next
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MultiSourceGrid_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles Me.CellValidating
    ' If this is an 'complex bound' column, attempt to set the value to the source object
    If (Columns(e.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName.Contains(".")) And e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        Try
            _commitAttempt = True
            CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Formatting) 'DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit Or DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("[during cell validating]" + vbNewLine + ex.Message)
            e.Cancel = True
        End Try
        _commitAttempt = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MultiSourceGrid_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Me.CellValueChanged
    ' If this is an 'complex bound' column, attempt to set the value to the source object
    If _commitAttempt Then
        Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(e.ColumnIndex)
        SetBindProperty(Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, Columns.Item(e.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName, cell.Value)
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is What I tried

```
public class DataBindingProjection
 {
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int apmntid { get; set; }
   public string servicedesc { get; set; }
   public string cusid { get; set; }
   public string empid { get; set; 
   public bool isdelivered { get; set; }
 }


     context = new HHCSEntities();

       var query = from d in context.DeliveryOrders
        join a in context.Appointments on d.Id equals a.Id
        join s in context.ServiceCategories on d.ServiceId equals s.ServiceId
        join e in context.Employees on d.EmpId equals e.EmpId
        select new DataBindingProjection
        {
            dono = d.Name,
            apmntid = a.Id,
            servicedesc = s.ServiceDesc,
            cusid = a.CusId,
            empid = d.EmpId,
            shortname = e.ShrtName,
            isdelivered = d.IsDelivered
        };

   dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
   dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";
   dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Id";
   dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "servicedesc";
   dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "apmntid";
   dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "empid";
   dataGridView1.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "isdelivered";
```

### You can use this way to update DateGrideView Table

```
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
bi.DataSource = query.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bi;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as my data5 example? It displays an editable copy of the data but any changes made in the DataGridView are not saved back to the database?